# UIStatusBar merge with UINavigationBar for iOS 7

Tags: uinavigationbar, statusbar, ios7

I have UINavigationBar which is green color and have UIStatusBar which is black color. It seems great for iOS 6, but now its transparent in iOS 7. So i just upgrade my app according to iOS 7 new design fundamentals and i want to merge my NavigationBar and StatusBar. How can i merge them ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to design new navigation bar image for iOS 7 specially with height (44 + 20[status bar height]) = 64 for 1x & 128 for 2x and you have to manually check for iOS versions if iOS 6 and earlier version set old image and for iOS 7 and later version setup new resized image.